# Need Help In Regex, substring between two brackets

Tags: php, regex

There is a main string:-

```
" ... [ ... SUB_STRING_TO_BE_SEARCHED ... ] ... [ ... THIS_SHOULD_NOT_GET_SELECTED ... ]"
```

step 1: I need to search for SUB_STRING_TO_BE_SEARCHED.

step 2: Then move to the left of the sub string (neglecting anything in between) and I'll find a bracket '['

step 3: Then move to the right of the sub string (neglecting anything in between) and I'll find a bracket ']'

step 4: Finally, I want to select everything between these two brackets and remove it.

Final string:-

```
" ...  ... [ ... THIS_SHOULD_NOT_GET_SELECTED ... ]"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$string = " ... [ ... SUB_STRING_TO_BE_SEARCHED ... ] ... [ ... THIS_SHOULD_NOT_GET_SELECTED ... ]";

$string = preg_replace('#\[.*?SUB_STRING_TO_BE_SEARCHED.*?\]#', '', $string);

var_dump($string);
```

If you want a more robust solution, you can use lookarounds:

```bash
(                               # group and capture to $1
    \[                          # match '['
    (?<=                        # look behind to see if there is
      \[                        # '['
    )                           # end of look-behind
    [^\[\]]*                    # any character except: '\[', '\]' (0 or more)
    SUB_STRING_TO_BE_SEARCHED   # 'SUB_STRING_TO_BE_SEARCHED'

    [^\[\]]*                    # any character except: '\[', '\]' (0 or more)
    (?=                         # look ahead to see if there is
      \]                        # ']'
    )                           # end of look-ahead
    \]                          # ']'
  )                             # end of capturing group 1
)
```

Output:

```
string(50) " ...  ... [ ... THIS_SHOULD_NOT_GET_SELECTED ... ]"
```

[**Regex101 Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/aJ5gU3)

Comment: I still think the more correct way to do this is using the `[^\]]*` instead of `.*` since your way could cause the issue of catching multiple square brackets until it finds that string (for example, swap the 2 expressions around and use your RegEx, you'll catch too much)

Answer (score 1):

This pattern could be used to find the bracketed string:

```
\[[^\]]*?SUB_STRING_TO_BE_SEARCHED.*?\]
```

The rest would just be to use a replace function.