# Need Help In Regex, substring between two regex

Tags: php, regex

Please read part 1 of this question:-

[Need Help In Regex, substring between two brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22769174/need-help-in-regex-substring-between-two-brackets)

```
$result = '';
$str = ' ... [ ... SUB_STRING_TO_BE_SEARCHED ... ] ... [ ... / ... SUB_STRING_TO_BE_SEARCHED ... ] ... [ ... THIS_SHOULD_NOT_GET_SELECTED ... ]';
$sub_str = '';
if( preg_match('#\[.*?'.$sub_str.'.*?\]#' , $str) ) {
    if ( preg_match( REGEX_2 , $str ) ) {
        $result = preg_replace( REGEX_3 , '', $str);
    } else {
        $result = preg_replace('#\[.*?'.$sub_str.'.*?\]#', '', $str);
    }
}
```

$result should be:-

```
$result = " ...  ... [ ... THIS_SHOULD_NOT_GET_SELECTED ... ]";
```

However, for $str_2:-

```
$str_2 = ' ... [ ... SUB_STRING_TO_BE_SEARCHED ... ] ... [ ... THIS_SHOULD_NOT_GET_SELECTED ... ]';
```

the $result should also remain:-

```
$result = " ...  ... [ ... THIS_SHOULD_NOT_GET_SELECTED ... ]";
```

## Explanation:-

Step 1: Ok, from previous question I can easily get this string:-

```
[ ... THIS_SHOULD_NOT_GET_SELECTED ... ]
```

Step 2:- REGEX_2 should check if this exists:-

```
[ ... / ... THIS_SHOULD_NOT_GET_SELECTED ... ]
```

(notice a forward slash, let's assume that it will appear only once between the `THIS_SHOULD_NOT_GET_SELECTED` and the left bracket `[`.)

Step 3:- If REGEX_2 is found then REGEX_3 should select this substring:-

```
[ ... SUB_STRING_TO_BE_SEARCHED ... ] ... [ ... / ... SUB_STRING_TO_BE_SEARCHED ... ]
```

---

**Another Examples:-**

```
$str_3 = ' ... [ ... AA ... ] ... [ ... / ... AA ... ] ... [ ... B ... ] ... [ ... AA ... ] ... [ ... / ... AA ... ] ... [ ... AA ... ]';
$substring_3 = 'AA'
$result = ' ...  ... [ ... B ... ] ...  ... ';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would opt for negated classes instead of `.*?`, and in case the `substring_3` is `AA`, then:

```
\[[^]]*?AA[^]]*?\](?:[^[]*\[[^]]*?/[^]]*?AA[^]]*?\])?
```

In:

```
$result = preg_replace('#\[[^]]*?'.$sub_str.'[^]]*?\](?:[^[]*\[[^]]*?/[^]]*?'.$sub_str.'[^]]*?\])?#', '', $str);
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/vO3bJ9)

---

```
\[          # Match [
  [^]]*?    # Any number of non ]
  AA        # The substr
  [^]]*?    # Any number of non ]
\]          # Match ]
(?:
  [^[]*     # Any number of non [
  \[        # Match [
    [^]]*?  # Any number of non ]
    /       # Match /
    [^]]*?  # Any number of non ]
    AA      # The substr
    [^]]*?  # Any number of non ]
  \]        # Match ]
)?          # Make this group optional
```

Comment: @OmarTariq Well, if you find something like that beautiful... :)